# SP2013 - howto list all the teamsites?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for a way to show/list **all** the teamsites on my SharePoint 2013 Foundation site. And if i click on the name, i have to redirected to the actual teamsite.

How can i realise this, so that **everyone** on the site can view all the teamsites?
I don't mind if it's build with Javascript or Powershell, just needs to work.

In forward, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use search and query for all sites with a given template:

```
"WebTemplate:STS"
```

Then you get everything else for free (clickable links, security trimming, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I managed it by this query: (contentclass:"STS_Web")

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each of your webapplication and then check it for Teamsite. Create a datasource and bind it to Grid or any control.

Ex:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))  
{     
   string templateID = web.WebTemplateId.ToString();
   if(templateID=="STS#0")
    //process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can use something like this

```
Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb | ? { $_.WebTemplate -match "STS"}
```

However PowerShell can not be used inside a Site collection

I think the best way is to use Search for this.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i show these links on my SharePoint page, so that the users can click on those links?